# Lua caching mysql data

Tags: mysql, caching, lua

I need to cache the data from mysql. (lua) Is there any method? I don't find any method or something to cache it. I need it because in my script I get many things from mysql in short time and this will be too laggy

Comment: i really don't believe that would be to "laggy", only if you would get huge results from thet databse. And usually database server and application server use gigabit ethernet and this is also not "laggy". did you try it ? eventually you can optimize it.

Comment: okay I will try it